# Using the current date in a Gatling test

Tags: datetime, gatling

I am trying to load test an application using Gatling, and the application needs the current date to be inserted into the test:

```
.formParam("dateCreation", "07/01/2015 16:48:04")
```

If it's hard coded it seems to upset the application being tested.

How can I generate the above string at the time of each request? (It's European format - `day/month/year`)

Scala isn't my strong point. I'm using Gatling 2.0.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a modern Java date API, like [joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), or JDK8's [DateTime](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) API.
With either API, you'll have to:

- first build a formatter for the desired pattern ("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"). Only build this once and for all as those are threadsafe (unlike Java's SimpleDateFormat).
- instead of passing a hard coded value, pass a [Session function](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.3/session/expression_el.html#expression) that fetch the current date and format it. It will look like (pseudo code):

  val formatter = ???

  .formParam("dateCreation", session => formatter.format(now()))

This way, the formatted date will be computed for each execution of this request.